# mysql: update with subquery,

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I have an update query with a select statement, which separately works. It's using it for the update that's not working.

```
update data set data.id = (select nid from node inner join data on node.title = data.name);
```

I get the error

> "You can't specify target table 'data' for update in FROM clause"

So, after digging around, I found that I could write include another select statement:

```
update data set data.id = (select nid from(select nid from node inner join data on node.title = data.name) AS temptable);
```

I get the error

> "Subquery returns more than 1 row "

So after more digging, I added an "ANY", as this is the common recommendation:

```
update data set data.id = (select nid from ANY (select nid from node inner join data on node.title = data.name) AS temptable);
```

and get

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(select nid from node inner join data on node.title = biblio_'
>   at line 1 "

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to update all rows in table `data` table, we can do something like this:

```
UPDATE data
  LEFT
  JOIN node
    ON node.title = data.name
   SET data.id = node.nid
```

NOTES:

If there are two or more rows in `node` that have the same value for `title` (which match `name` in `data`), the value of `nid` from one of the matching rows will be assigned, but it's indeterminate which of those row.

If there are values of `name` in the `data` table which are not found in the `node` table (in the `title` column), then a NULL value will be assigned to the `id` column.

Some tweaks to the query can modify this behavior.

We can achieve a similar result using a correlated subquery. Here's an example:

```
UPDATE data
   SET data.id = ( SELECT node.nid
                     FROM node
                    WHERE node.title = data.name
                    ORDER BY node.nid
                    LIMIT 1
                 )
```

Comment: Apart from more concise syntax, I presume this will also be a lot faster in terms of execution time.