# Update statement does not work while select returns the matching rows

Tags: mysql

I had a `users` table mapped to a `schools` table.
However, recently I've introduced a `courses` table which is mapped to the `schools` table now.
I am trying to break the relation between users and school and link them through courses instead.

I am trying to update the affected rows in `users` table using a join, however no rows are being updated. I don't see any error message either.

When I use the same query to select the matching rows, it fetches 20 rows.

What could be the possible reasons an Update query would fail? I checked and verified there are rows which needs update.

**Update Query:**

`UPDATE users INNER JOIN courses ON users.course_id = courses.school_id SET users.course_id = courses.id`

**Select Query:**

`SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN courses on users.course_id = courses.school_id`

Could it be because I am trying to update the same fields used in the JOIN clause?

**Edit**

Table Structures:

Schools:

```
id | name
--------------
1  | St. Joseph\'s
2  | St. Mary\'s
```

Courses:

```
id | school_id
--------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
```

Users:

```
id | name | course_id
---------------------
1  | Ray  | 1
2  | Jake | 1
3  | Sam  | 1
```

**Note:**
`users.course_id` is actually mapped to `schools.id` right now.
Need to map it to `courses.id` instead.

Comment: 1) Do you get any error message back when you run the update query? 2) Do you have a FK relationship defined on users.course_id field?

Comment: 1) No error messages.
2) No FK Relationship.

Comment: Better to share the table structure with sample data.

Comment: I'm suspicious of users.course_id = courses.school_id maybe this should be users.course_id = courses.course_id better if we could see sample data

Comment: Sample data shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. The update statement "works" but your logic doesn't.

```
drop table if exists courses;
create table courses (id int, school_id int);
insert into courses values
(10 , 1),
(2  , 1),
(3  , 2);
drop table if exists Users;
create table users (id int, name varchar(4), course_id int);
insert into users values
(1   ,'Ray' , 1),
(2   ,'Jake', 1),
(3   ,'Sam' , 1);

UPDATE users INNER JOIN courses ON users.course_id = courses.school_id SET users.course_id = courses.id  ;

select * from users;
```

result

```
+------+------+-----------+
| id   | name | course_id |
+------+------+-----------+
|    1 | Ray  |        10 |
|    2 | Jake |        10 |
|    3 | Sam  |        10 |
+------+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, SQL first retrieves the rows that match your join. Since users.course_id does not have a value, it will retrieve no rows.

You might want to have something like this:

```
UPDATE  Users
SET     users.course_id = courses.id
FROM    users 
INNER JOIN courses 
    on users.school_id= courses.school_id
```

In this query I assume that a user has a school_id (from the initial two table situation). Note that your SELECT statement has a join on:

```
users.course_id = courses.school_id
```

which maybe should be (??)

```
users.school_id = courses.school_id
```

Comment: According to the question: "When I use the same query to select the matching rows, it fetches 20 rows." This implies that the course_id field is indeed populated.

Comment: There is no users.school_id

Comment: Check Sample data

Comment: Also, I am using MySQL

Comment: Hi Akshay, using your sample data the SELECT statement returns 6 rows (in T-SQL): the INNER JOIN returns 2 records per user (since there are 2 courses for school 1). The UPDATE returns 3 rows, again in T-SQL. Could it be that MySQL doesn't like indeterminate joins in an update. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023658/mysql-update-with-subquery to see if this relates to your situation